# Optimizing animation performance in WebKit on Linux

Tags: c++, css, linux, webkit, gtk

How does one optimize a compiled WebKit browser to take the best advantage of the GPU?

**Background**

My team and I are working on configuring a Linux box (CentOS) to display full screen HTML with smooth, CSS-driven animations. The box has more than adequate GPU and CPU power and is able to play back these animations easily in Chromium.

However, we are attempting to use pure WebKit to render these animations both by using [WebKitGTK+](https://webkitgtk.org) in Python and by compiling WebKit to a simplistic browser from the source.

**Current Status**

In both "pure" webkit applications, the animations are vastly slower than on Chromium, which is making us scratch our heads to answer what *exactly* is different between the two. We understand Chromium uses Blink, a fork of WebKit, and we currently believe the difference in performance is due to the fact that Chromium, Safari, and other WebKit-based browsers each use their own graphics component that is separate from WebKit and Web Core itself, based on what we've read.

It would be great if we could customize our WebKit build to perform even to half the specs of what we're seeing in Chromium but we're not sure where to start.

**I'm wondering**...

1. Is our assumption about the separate graphics component correct?
2. What options exist for us to optimize CSS animation performance in a "pure" WebKit browser such as ours?

Comment: Why not base your fork in Blink then? What WebKit version? Also, although jsperf.com seems to be down for the last 2 days, when I upgraded to Chrome (Mac) to 64.0.xxxx and ran benchmarks, HTML rendering performance was THE WORST of Chrome's ever recorded there. Maybe there's "bad" release of WebKit which Blink inherited?

Comment: 1. Base our code you mean? Chromium/Blink does not have a license that meets our needs. 2. Not sure if we're talking about the same thing. Chromium is our "good" comparison. We're seeing poor performance in a purely-built WebKit.

Comment: Hi, how do you compile Webkit ? There is maybe some parameters to set to use more efficiently your arch

Comment: @Jaay I'll get back on how we compile ours, but we're also testing with the latest WebkitGTK and getting the same results. We've tried turning all kinds of flags on as well.

Comment: To @marekful's question, the performance difference is astronomical, not like performance differences one would observe between the major browsers on an OS, it appears more like pure webkit is missing a major component that all major browsers have to some extent.

Comment: Not sure if this will be useful. But came across one scenario which I would like to share. Recently we developed web page which uses lot of animations using transform3d, the animation worked pretty well on chrome in desktop and on ios 11 in iphone 6plus. But performed really really bad on ios10 in iphone.6 and the page used to crash pretty badly. After going through tones of optimization procedured and debugging we found that the transform3d layers that are created are having a different memory foot print on both the implementations and that's why the page was crashing.

Comment: ..so we finally decided to change the animation a bit so we can reduce some transform3d's. The reason why I am saying this is there might be some difference between the webkit versions so you can look at that angle. And another idea is to see if the frame size processed by the GPU is same on chromium and webkit.

Comment: That's great info, @karthick. I wouldn't have thought to look at that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if i can help you with your Project, but one of the things i have learned lately is that we can **hardware-accelerate graphics-intensive CSS** features by offloading them to the GPU for better rendering performance in the browser.

Right now most of the modern browsers are shipped with hardware acceleration. They will use it when they ***see*** that the DOM will benefit from it. A strong indicator is the 3D transformation.

Lets say that you wanna place your DOM with a position absolute and raise it above the parent container. Instead of that you could actually use `-webkit-transform: translate3d(10px,10px,10px);` That will resolve into a 3D rendering even if we don't animate the element at all. Even if you set zero values, it will still trigger the Graphic Acceleration.

**TIP** If you see any flickering then try adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` and `-webkit-perspective: 1000;`

**Now lets talk about the basics of CSS**

You should know that the most important thing about how browsers **READ** your CSS selectors, is that they read them from **right to left.** That means that in the selector `ul > li img[alt="test.png"]` the first thing interpreted is `img[alt="test.png"]`. The first part is also referred as the "key selector".

So first things first, **IDs are the most efficient, leaving universals the least.** So you could rewrite your CSS code replacing the global ones (when aren't really needed) with **IDs**.

An other way of slowing your browser down is by adding the **global selector upfront. (div#my-div)**  Something that Chrome is actually doing by default on inspect mode. **That will GREATLY slow your browser down**.

By far the worst case is the **Descendant selectors**. Even a selector that fails (when your selector doesn't match anything) is better than `html body div ul li a {  }`

One more thing, that is extremely helpful and clean is the CSS3 selectors (:last-child). Even if those selectors help us and make our life easier, they rip your Browser down. You might not see any difference in performance on a small scale application, but when you introduce them in Enterprise Applications, you will notice that they are slowing down your Rendering.

So to sum up. I just told you that replacing all of your selectors with IDs and applying style on every single element by ID will make your app super fast, but on the other hand it will be a bit silly. It would be extremely hard to maintain and also non-semantic. Thus you should consider replacing most of the selectors with IDs but don't sacrifice **semantics / maintainability** for **efficient CSS**

Also you could check an interesting test [here](https://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/).

Now that i think of it, i should start with the CSS basics. Oh well, i hope i helped you even a little with your Project. Cheers

Comment: Thanks, this is a good point and something I forgot to mention. In our CSS we are using the `transform` property wherever we can to ensure usage of the GPU. Do you think the `-webkit` prefix would make a difference if the non-prefixed property is already supported?

Comment: @AdamGrant Probably not. I have never experienced any difference in the past and most of my Development is on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

> According to [**Guil Hernandez**'s article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css) CSS animations, transforms and transitions are not automatically GPU accelerated, and instead execute from the browser’s slower software rendering engine. So what exactly forces the browser to swap to GPU mode? Many browsers provide GPU acceleration by means of certain CSS rules.

Example:

```
.cube {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(250px,250px,250px)
   rotate3d(250px,250px,250px,-120deg)
   scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
}
```